# How to print a text and rendered mathjax text in the same line

Tags: html, mathjax

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fw5D.png)

Hi, for a past few days i've been working on a html website related to Physics, Chemistry and Maths. To print symbols related to these subjects in my page i used mathjax. But i was able to print the rendered equations or symbols only in a new line.

It would be really helpful If someone suggests me how to print my text and the symbol in the same line.

Thanks in Advance